# Multiple Inheritance in Java allowed with Object class?

Tags: java, object, multiple-inheritance

In Java, they say that Multiple Inheritance is not supported. Also its a fact, that each class in Java extends class Object. So if I write :

```
public class ThreadInstance extends Thread {
}
```

How does this compile? ThreadInstance here is actually extending Thread as well as Object. Isn't it multiple Inheritance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By multiple inheritance you should understand inheriting multiple classes at the same time, e.g. it's impossible to create a

```
public class ThreadInstance extends Thread, Object {
}
```

because class hierarchy would look like this:

```
ThreadInstance
^            ^
Thread       Object
```

When you define your `ThreadInstance` like you did, the `ThreadInstance` inherits `Object` too, but it *first* inherits thread.

```
ThreadInstance
      ^
    Thread
      ^
    Object
```

There is no multiple inheritance there.

Answer (score 0):

Your class extends `Thread` but `Thread` already extends `Object` so it's still single-inheritance as it follows the same line of inheritance

`Object` is *implicitly* inherited by every class. In your `ThreadInstance` class, `Thread` is *explicitly* inherited.

Thus every Java class except `Object` must have a super-class. There's nothing all to special about implicit inheritance, it's simply there to reduce boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

Your class that extends that other class, but it extends Object, too, so you're still in one line of inheritance, not two.

Eg.
ThreadInstance extends Thread, but Thread in turn extends Object so cant I say ThreadInstance extends Object.